# Javascript: How to change to not open in new page

Tags: php, javascript, header

I need to  change my header.php file and want to my "social" icons open in same window.
Now, wnen click on then they are opening in new window. Can you help me to edit header.php than they open in same window?

Here is the source code:

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!--[if ie]><meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/><![endif]-->

        <title><?php wp_title( ' - ', true, 'right' ); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

        <?php if ( of_get_option('sc_enablemeta')== '1') { ?>

        <!-- meta -->
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_metadescription')  ?>">
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php wp_title(); ?>, <?php echo of_get_option('sc_metakeywords')  ?>" />
        <meta name="revisit-after" content="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_revisitafter')  ?> days" />
        <meta name="author" content="www.site5.com">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( of_get_option('sc_enablerobot')== '1') { ?>

        <!-- robots -->
        <meta name="robots" content="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_metabots')  ?>" />
        <meta name="googlebot" content="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_metagooglebot')  ?>" />
        <?php } ?>

        <!-- icons & favicons (for more: http://themble.com/support/adding-icons-favicons/) -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico">   

        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->




        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">

        <!-- wordpress head functions -->
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <!-- end of wordpress head -->



        <?php if(of_get_option('sc_css_code') != '') { ?> 
        <!-- custom css -->  
            <?php load_template( get_template_directory() . '/custom.css.php' );?>
        <!-- custom css -->
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if(of_get_option('sc_customtypography') == '1') { ?>     
        <!-- custom typography-->   
            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_headingfontlink') != '') { ?>
            <?php echo stripslashes(html_entity_decode(of_get_option('sc_headingfontlink')));?>
        <!-- custom typography -->
            <?php } ?>
            <?php load_template( get_template_directory() . '/custom.typography.css.php' );?>
        <?php } ?>


        <?php if(of_get_option('sc_colorscheme') != '') { ?> 
            <!-- custom color scheme css -->  
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/library/css/color-schemes/<?php echo of_get_option('sc_colorscheme') ?>/styles.css">
        <?php } ?>



    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>


        <div id="page">


            <div class="container clearfix">


                <div id="pre-header">
                    <!-- begin #socialIcons -->
                    <div id="social-icons">
                        <ul id="social-links">
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_facebook')!='') : ?>
                            <li class="facebook-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_facebook') ?>" class="facebook" id="social-01" title="<?php _e( 'Join Us on Facebook!', 'site5framework' ); ?>">Facebook</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_twitter')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="twitter-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_twitter') ?>" class="twitter" id="social-02" title="<?php _e( 'Follow Us on Twitter', 'site5framework' ); ?>">Twitter</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_googleplus')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="google-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_googleplus') ?>" id="social-03" title="<?php _e( 'Google+', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="google">Google</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_dribble')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="dribbble-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_dribble') ?>" id="social-04" title="<?php _e( 'Dribble', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="dribbble">Dribble</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_vimeo')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="vimeo-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_vimeo') ?>" id="social-05" title="<?php _e( 'Vimeo', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="vimeo">Vimeo</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_skype')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="skype-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_skype') ?>" id="social-06" title="<?php _e( 'Skype', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="skype">Skype</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_linkedin')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="linkedin-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_linkedin') ?>" id="social-07" title="<?php _e( ' LinkedIn', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="linkedin">Linkedin</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_pinterest')!=''): ?>
                            <li class="pinterest-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_pinterest') ?>" id="social-09" title="<?php _e( 'Pinterest', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="pinterest">Pinterest</a></li>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <?php if(of_get_option('sc_rss')=='1'): ?>
                                <li class="rss-link"><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_extrss') ?  of_get_option('sc_extrss') : bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" id="social-08" title="<?php _e( 'RSS', 'site5framework' ); ?>" class="rss">RSS Feeds</a></li>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                     <select id="responsive-social-menu" onchange = "javascript:window.location.replace(this.value);"><option selected="selected" ><?php _e('Social Links', 'site5framework'); ?></select>
                     <!-- end #socialIcons -->
                </div>
                <!-- end #pre-header -->





                <header role="banner" id="header" class="clearfix">

                        <!-- begin #logo -->
                        <?php if ( !of_get_option('sc_clogo')== '') { ?>
                        <hgroup id="logo-wrapper">
                            <h1><a id="logo" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                                <img src="<?php echo of_get_option('sc_clogo'); ?>" alt="<?php echo bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" />
                            </a></h1>

                        </hgroup>

                        <?php } else { ?>

                        <hgroup id="logo-wrapper">
                            <h1><a id="logo" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                                <?php if( !of_get_option('sc_clogo_text')== '') {
                                    echo of_get_option('sc_clogo_text'); 
                                    } else {
                                    bloginfo( 'name' );
                                }
                                ?>
                            </a></h1>
                            <h5 id="tagline"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h5>
                        </hgroup>

                        <?php }?>
                        <!-- end #logo -->



                        <!-- begin #topMenu -->
                        <div id="navigation-wrapper" class="clearfix">
                            <select id = "responsive-main-nav-menu" onchange = "javascript:window.location.replace(this.value);"><option selected="selected" ><?php _e('Menu', 'site5framework'); ?></option></select>

                            <nav id="main-navigation" class="main-menu">
                            <?php
                            site5_main_nav( array(
                             'container' =>false,
                             'menu_class' => '',
                             'echo' => true,
                             'before' => '',
                             'after' => '',
                             'link_before' => '',
                             'link_after' => '',
                             'depth' => 0
                             )
                             );
                             // Adjust using Menus in Wordpress Admin ?>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end #topMenu -->

                </header> <!-- end header -->


            </div>
```

Comment: You're merely dumping a lot of code. Have you ever heard something like [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: `onchange = "javascript:window.location.replace(this.value);"` should be keeping the same window. Do you have some other event listener on the `social-links` `li`s?

Comment: Maybe should be keep the same window but not. You can see url http://spravka.eu/delivery

Comment: Maybe should be keeping the same window, but not. You can see site on http://spravka.eu/delivery

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code on your website: http://spravka.eu/delivery/ I can see the `target="_blank"` attribute set on the anchor elements. This will cause the links to open in a new tab or window (depending on browser).

If you remove the `target` attribute then you won't have this problem. Unless you're also doing something funky with JavaScript.